# iOS: Open document of an app from another app and save back to the called app

Tags: ios, ios7, document, file-sharing

In my application, I want to open excel documents listed in my application using any excel editor. Edit it and save back to my application only. Can this be possible on iOS?

As I looked into this, I could open using an excel editor, edit the file, but file is saved  in the called `application's folder`, not in my `application folder`.

Is there any way I could achieve this? Kindly suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: callback urls are the only way AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

iOS does not provide a feature directly to support this. But there are two ways to achieve your desired behavior.

In both cases the apps have to cooperate and conform to a specification. The calling app passes information to the other app, which the other app then uses to send data back eventually.

## Custom URL schemes

Apps can voluntarily communicate with custom URL schemes. Some apps support [x-callback-url](http://x-callback-url.com) for that.

## UIDocumentInteractionController annotation

Another possibility is passing an annotation dictionary to the UIDocumentInteractionController that opens the other app. QuickOffice has a [save back API](http://qocom-ec2-dev-1-el-1056185577.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/partner_solutions/save_back/), that could be used like that. It seems to be deprecated though and the documentation has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS each application exists in its own sandbox, separated from other apps except for several rather indirect modes of interaction, such as registering URLs and [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html). The security benefits of this approach are fairly clear, but of course they do have certain drawbacks.

One such drawback is that allowing app B to save data to the sandbox of app A would defeat the purpose of sandboxing.

On a jail-broken device on the other hand...

Comment: Can you suggest for the above answer given by @RAJA ? is that possible?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573689/uidocumentinteractioncontroller) for more information. It describes what you are trying to achieve, but requires that app B also has the ability to save and open documents in another app.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no option to save documents to our application from the external application. As you mentioned, we are having only option to open-url document using our application programmatically.

If the external application have option to open the documents through other applications, then there is an option to open/save that edited document through your application.